# Аndroid файловая система

Tags: android, файлы

Объясните мне пожалуйста почему когда я сохраняю файл в загрузки телефона, этот файл не показывается обычной файловой системой телефона а если я через `рутБраузер` открываю то в загрузках по указанному пути он есть. Как мне сделать его доступным для пользователя? и я очень хочу разобраться с файловой системой и понять как это работает(файл находящийся совершенно в другом месте от приложения остается не доступным почему?)`(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Download/" + nhj + ".xlsx"))) {
                workbook2.write(out);`

Comment: Это может зависеть от версии ОС. С 9-10 версии очень сильно всё поменяли в сторону усложнения доступа к внешним путям и доступа к файлам других приложений.

Comment: 9 версия. А есть какие либо методы чтоб это обойти?

Comment: Есть, вроде, какие-то хаки, но их быстро закроют. Не совсем хак - понизить targetSdkVersion до 26, например. Тогда перестанут применяться правила новых версий ОС к работе с файловой системой. Но такое приложение нельзя будет отправить в PlayMarket. Так что если вам действительно нужна такая функциональность и надо выкладывать в маркет - смотрите документацию по этому поводу. Но там всё сложно, насколько я помню.

Comment: Сохраняйте в getExternalFilesDir